# How do you write an invitation to dinner in spanish?

Tags: traducción, españa, cortesía

How would sound an invitation to dinner in spanish? For example:

> Would you like to have dinner with me next week?

or maybe there is a specific phrase?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't say anything about the context I'll give some options.

You could use

> Me gustaría invitarte a cenar.
>
> Te invito a cenar la próxima semana.

You could be seeing this in an informal email, for example. If you want to go more informal (within the context of asking someone out on a date):

> Te gustaría cenar conmigo la próxima semana?
>
> Quieres cenar conmigo la próxima semana?
>
> Qué te parecería cenar conmigo la próxima semana?
>
> Querrías cenar conmigo la próxima semana?
>
> Te propongo cenar un día de la próxima semana / Te propongo una cena la próxima semana.

If is formal (like if your are inviting a client for a business dinner) you should used the *usted* form instead:

> Me gustaría invitarle a cenar
>
> Le invito a cenar

But these ones are usually worded different, since you might be doing the invitation within a certain context:

> Nuestra empresa tiene el placer de invitarle a cenar...
>
> Nuestra empresa tiene el gusto de invitarle a cenar...

Comment: @PirvuGeorgian, next time don't be afraid to try translating it yourself first. People in this site are friendly and will help you improve your Spanish.

Comment: If you want to invite to dinner at a Chilean, do not tell "cenar", sounds cheesy. In Chile we say "te invito a comer" unless something extremely formal, and even then it sounds exaggerated or foreign.

Comment: @Rodrigo, en Cuba suscede lo mismo, pero si quien lo dice es una persona de otro país, se entendería perfectamente.

Comment: @Rodrigo, eso es muy interesante. Usáis "almorzar" para alguna de las comidas? En España son: desayuno, comida (sobre las 2pm) y cena (sobre las 9pm). Casi nadie usa almuerzo. Puede depender el uso del término de la hora a la que se come o cena en vuestros países?

Comment: Nosotros en Chile almorzamos al medio día y comemos en la noche, aunque por supuesto "comer", como actividad general, puede usarse para cualquier momento del día.

Comment: desayuno, almuerzo y comida es como se usa en cuba, y por supuesto las meriendas..jejej

Comment: thanks @Diego.  Next time i will try translate myself and then i will post the question.

Comment: Note that in Spanish, "invitar" carries the connotation of paying for someone else. If your intention is only to eat with them (but they pay for their own meal), don't use that word!